# MVC6 razor how to detect debug mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous versions of Razor I would conditionally load minified/debug versions of scripts by rendering a partial view that looked something like this:

```
@if (Context.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    <script src="~/debug.js"></script>
}
else
{
    <script src="~/release.js"></script>
}
```

If MVC6, vNext, VS2015, or whatever you call it :) I don't know how to accomplish this. Anyone know how?

Comment: In previous versions you should have been using bundling.

Comment: I've used bundling but I find it inferior to preprocessing the files with a task runner such as gulp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In MVC6, you can use the environment tag helper to load different versions of scripts depending for Development vs Production environments. This is based on the value of the value of the ASPNET_ENV environment variable.

```
<environment names="Development">            
    <script src="~/debug.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/release.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Bundling and minification would be handled using a task like Gulp or Grunt.

I have outlined the new approach in detail here:
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/05/web-optimization-development-and-production-in-asp-net-mvc6.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A bit old, but you could just create a ViewBag (or session object) in your controller and pass it to a ViewBag like this

```
#if DEBUG
            ViewBag.IsDebug = true; 
#endif
```

Then in your view:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsDebug)
    {
    <script src="~/debug.js"></script>
}
else
{
    <script src="~/release.js"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) in asp.net mvc

Comment: The question is specifically about MVC6, which does not support the older runtime bundling.